# Strange issue giving margin right to my menu items

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to turn a desktop design to a tablet one.

And I'm doing now a media query for 768px, and so I have my menu with 768px, and I want to give `margin-left` and `margin-right` to my menu items.

And when I give `margin-left`, everything works fine, but `margin-right` is not working, and my last menu item that is my search input appears outside my 768px.

Can someone please help me understanding what is happening? What I have so far:

[image: screenshot of menu bar]

My JSFiddle with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ra3zc/3/

My HTML:

```html
<section id="menu-container">
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>    
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li style="border-top:none;"><a href="#">Link 1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li style="border-top:none;"><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li style="border-top:none;"><a href="#">Link 3.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
            <li id="search_list">
                <form id="search">
                    <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
                    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</section>
```

My CSS is a bit long so I’m not putting it here.

Comment: First of all, you neglected to override the default padding the `ul` gets from the browser stylesheet (which you could have easily figured out yourself via your browser’s developer tools). And second of all, `width:768px` plus `margin-left:5px` for the `ull` are still wider than the 768px width of the surrounding `nav` element …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#menu ul 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 768px;   
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

your `#menu ul` should not be 768px because it occupied all the #menu range, try to change it to 500px or less.

Comment: Thanks you, thats right I forgot that! But Im still with a problem with this code and I think its that that is broken my page structure, but its something very strange, so I´ll ask other question because Im getting crazy with this issue. But your solution here its correct, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try foundation 5 next time,in your case  its really useful for tablet and mobile versions.